# Can't install Bastille on ubuntu saucy 13.10

Tags: 13.10, software-installation

I followed the [Ubuntu Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BastilleLinux).  I enabled universe repository. But apt-get and aptitude both fail with "no candidate found".  I assume this means Bastille is not available for Saucy?  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Do you think it would be risky to install the last 13.04 version?  Not sure how to do that but I'll research it, so long as it's an acceptable thing to try.

Comment: I'm running 13.10 on a system I'm thinking of rebuilding.  So I think I'll try to run Bastille from 13.04 and see what happens.  What I like about Bastille is that it's supposed to make it easier to harden ubuntu.  I know I can get in trouble with the tool but I'll risk it.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/bastille the package indeed no longer exists.

Normally, while there is a reason for a package to get removed, you can indeed install the older version by adding the relevant lines for the older Ubuntu release to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` (do not remove the lines for saucy, though):

```
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse >>/etc/apt.sources.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bastille
```

Note that it [appears buggy](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bastille/+bug/540499), so you may or may not have success in running – or even installing – it.